# NSE Numerical IQ Test no.12: 759802, 358829, 847123,?

Tags: number-sequence

This is a question from the [NSE Numerical IQ Test](https://free.ultimaiq.net/nse.htm) by Theodosis Prousalis and Ivan Ivec:

> **12)** 759802, 358829, 847123, ?

After 2 hours, I can't figure out the answer. I've only made these observations:

> 1. 829 - 358 = 471 with appears in the next number.
>  2. From 02 to 35 you need 33
>  3. From 29 to 84 you need 55
>  4. 759 + 88 = 847
>  5. 123 + 759 = 882

But I'm not sure if these observations are helpful to solve this sequence.

What is the next number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think x is:

> 328352

The pattern seems to be:

> Add digits next to each other, and then add the digits of that sum to get a single digit, wrap the first number around as the "next" digit to be added with the last digit.

Example:

> 7 + 5 = 12 --> 3
>  5 + 9 = 14 --> 5
>  9 + 8 = 17 --> 8
>  8 + 0 = 8  --> 8
>  0 + 2 = 2  --> 2
>  2 + 7 = 9  --> 9

Therefore x is:

> 8 + 4 = 12 --> 3
>  4 + 7 = 11 --> 2
>  7 + 1 = 8  --> 8
>  1 + 2 = 3  --> 3
>  2 + 3 = 5  --> 5
>  3 + 8 = 11 --> 2

Comment: I checked with the website and it is correct! +1